# Accessing value from key with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. This is giving me `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I log the values inside the objects?

```js
let spaceship = {
  passengers: null
};

(spaceship.passengers = [{ name: "Mike" }, { ability: "teleportation" }]),
  [{ name: "David" }, { ability: "cook" }];

let firstPassenger = spaceship.passengers[0];
console.log(firstPassenger.ability);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear This is giving me undefined?

Comment: To me it looks like the code you pasted here has syntax errors - spaceship.paseengers is surround with paranthesis and then unassigned array.. is your javascript code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, this statement:

```
(spaceship.passengers = [{ name: "Mike" }, { ability: "teleportation" }]),
  [{ name: "David" }, { ability: "cook" }];
```

is syntactically like

```
(foo = 1), 2;
```

This assigns `1` to `foo`, not `[1, 2]` as you expect. In your example, you assign to `spaceship.passengers` the value `[{ name: "Mike" }, { ability: "teleportation" }]`. Your `firstPassenger` is thus `{ name: "Mike" }`, and has no `ability`. The one with the ability is your second, nameless passenger.

What you likely wanted to write instead is:

```
spaceship.passengers = [{ name: "Mike", ability: "teleportation" },
  { name: "David", ability: "cook" }];
```

or formatted a bit more nicely:

```
spaceship.passengers = [
  { name: "Mike", ability: "teleportation" },
  { name: "David", ability: "cook" },
];
```

It might sound preachy, but good formatting is key to good programming, as it allows you to see the structure of your code at a glance. It is clear in my last example what is the first passenger; in yours, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are defining the array of objects the wrong way, I think you want the `ability` and `name` into one object:

```js
let spaceship = {
  passengers: null
};

spaceship.passengers = [{ name: "Mike" , ability: "teleportation" }, { name: "David" , ability: "cook" }];

let firstPassenger = spaceship.passengers[0];
console.log(firstPassenger.ability);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do, do you want to set the value of the object?

I have provided the following example, you can try to compare the two and confirm whether this is what you want

Regarding your json string, I suggest that you redesign it as in my example. This is because all the attributes of an object are best placed in an object. This will make the scope clearer.

```js
let spaceship = {
  passengers: null
};

spaceship.passengers = [{
  name: "Mike",
  ability: "teleportation"
}, {
  name: "David",
  ability: "cook"
}];

const passengers = spaceship.passengers;

passengers.forEach(obj =>
  console.log(`name: ${obj.name}, ability: ${obj.ability}`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined object in a wrong way.
You should define object like this to get the desired result

```
let spaceship = {
    passengers: null
  };

        spaceship.passengers = [
            {
               name: "Mike" , ability: "teleportation" 
            },
            {
               name: "David" , ability: "cook" 
            }
          ];
     let firstPassenger = spaceship.passengers[0];
          console.log(firstPassenger.ability);
```